# Flutter Change Property of the Widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I created a custom widget for search using Row TextFormField.
Now I want to show loading until search process completed in the same widget. I want to create property in and change it through on change.

My Widget

```
  const BtxtSearchNew({
    Key? key,
    required this.textController,
    this.onChanged,
    this.hintText = "Search",
    this.autoFocus,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.focusNode,
    bool loading = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final TextEditingController textController;
  final onChanged;
  final hintText;
  final autoFocus;
  final onSubmit;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;

  @override
  State<BtxtSearchNew> createState() => _BtxtSearchNewState();
}
```

How I want to use it

```
          textController: controller.searchInput,
          onChanged: (value) {
            loading = true; // my widget property change Search Started
            controller.debouncer.call(() {
              controller.searchText.value =
                  controller.searchInput.text.toLowerCase();
            loading = false; //  my widget property change Search Ended
           });
          },
          hintText: "Search by Date or Employee Name or Employee ID",
        ),
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.htm). First, define the `loading` variable:

```dart
class _BtxtSearchNewState extends State<BtxtSearchNew> {
  bool loading = false;

  // ...
}
```

and use it inside `onChanged` callback:

```dart
onChanged: (value) async {
  setState(() {
    loading = true;
  });

  // your asynchronous code goes here ...
  
  setState(() {
    loading = false;
  });
},
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To call the `onChanged` callback passed as a parameter, you can do this:

```dart
const BtxtSearchNew({
  // ...
  this.onChanged,
}) : super(key: key);
  // ...
  final ValueChanged<TheType>? onChanged; // change TheType to your value type

  @override
  State<BtxtSearchNew> createState() => _BtxtSearchNewState();
}
```

```dart
onChanged: (value) async {
  setState(() {
    loading = true;
  });

  await widget.onChanged?.call(value);
  
  setState(() {
    loading = false;
  });
},
```

Comment: I want to change property from my Widget instance onchanged, not from class onchanged.

Comment: There is no class onChanged. I cut the code to show you minimal changes you have to make on your code

Comment: Basically, in your code you have `_BtxtSearchNewState`. You should add that 1 line (`bool loading = false;`). And you have `onChanged` shown on your code. You just need to put my additional codes (the setState part) on that one

Comment: I am already using this. I wanted to change property of flutter widget like vb and other software.

Comment: Try my edited answer, is that what you're trying to achieve?